# Is it possible to capture results runs from within a node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Suppose I have a function that look like this:

```
def foo () {
  node('some-node-that-has-bash') {
    return sh(script: 'ls', returnStdout:true )
  }
}
```

While running this in a jenkins pipeline, the `foo` seems to return `null`

Is there a way to pass the result from within the node block and pass it to `foo()` ?

Answer (score 1):

assign the return value of your shell command to a variable defined in an outer scope.

```
def foo () {
  def returnValue
  node('some-node-that-has-bash') {
    returnValue = sh(script: 'ls', returnStdout:true )
  }
  return returnValue
}
```